# Flickering cursor with 3 monitor setup

Tags: nvidia, cursor

I have freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04 and for some reason when I have all 3 monitors enabled I get a strange mouse flicker/lag.. but when I disable them and leave one enabled it's all fine.

I have 2x Nvidia GTX670s

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed a driver yet for your graphics card? You may need to use the opensource driver to solve the problem. Try this link for more information on opensource drivers:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia